# What is front/back matter?

Tags: structure, tools, chapters

I was browsing around for different writing tools and one of the sites mentioned tools for front and back matter in addition to tools for chapter planning. What is front / back matter?

Comment: Around the chapters as a whole, right? Not as in each individual chapter?

Comment: @Tommy Myron Whoops yeah... Around ALL the chapters. Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something *around* the chapters?

Front matter is usually all the stuff that comes in a book before the start of the story/main body of the book. Title page, copyright page, acknowledgements, table of contents, etc.

Back matter would be citations or index for non-fiction. For fiction, I'd say back matter is fairly optional, but it might include an "about the author" or list of other books available, sometimes the first chapter of the next book, or whatever.

Pretty much anything that isn't in the original manuscript would be front or back matter.